# PHP is having issues in connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Regarding my PHP and Apache it gives perfect result but when I come to MySQL it always has some issues. I have already tried but still it gives me error like

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

and

> you have missing parameter  and missing 2 parameter

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='';
$db_name='testdb';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password") or die ("couldnt able to connect with database");
mysqli_select_db("$con", 'testdb')or die ("No database");
echo "succesful connection";
?>
```

Comment: We need code examples to review the error's you are getting...

Comment: <?php

$db_host='localhost';
$db_username='root';
$db_password='';
$db_name='testdb';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password") or die ("couldnt able to connect with database");
mysqli_select_db("$con", 'testdb')or die ("No database");
echo "succesful connection";

?>

Comment: In the connection you also need to pass the `$db_name ` parameter: `mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password, $db_name)`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPractice\testdb.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPractice\testdb.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPractice\testdb.php on line 8
No database

Comment: Take away the `"` from the variables

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPPractice\testdb.php on line 8

Comment: Also from the `mysqli_select_db("$con", 'testdb')` - >`mysqli_select_db($con, 'testdb')`